# What's the recommended mechanism to centrally configure logging with log4j2 across a distributed environment?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I'm trying to build a centralized mechanism to configure my log4j2 loggers. The purpose of this is to create a web application to control the configuration of a given logger, no matter where it is deployed. In other words, my loggers should be able to detect any change in the central configuration panel and reconfigure automatically.

Right now, I'm experimenting with having a database with 3 tables (apps <-- loggers <-- appenders) and a custom configuration factory and a custom configuration, however I'm not sure if this approach is the more appropriate.

Any recommendation or guide is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's fine. Have you considered the case when the client can not connect? Will you use the latest available configuration or the default configuration?

Comment: Yes, Paul. In my servlet I checked if there is nothing from the database call and send a default XML configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the following solution, which comply with my requirements, but can be enhanced in many ways:

- I've created a servlet that goes to the database and loads the loggers configuration.
- I have set a configuration file that uses XInclude to load log4j2 configuration XML by the servlet's URI.
- I didn't use the ConfigurationFactory and the Configuration I was working on... got bored of them :-)

This works like a charm... **however, be warned that there is no way at this moment that Log4J2 can detect any changes in the remote configuration when using XInclude**. [It was oppened a report in JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-911) to let them know that xinclude does not honor the monitorInterval when including the configuration this way.

This is the configuration file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" name="Log4J2Config"
monitorInterval="5" status="Trace">
   <Properties>
    <Property name="Pattern">%d{ISO8601}|APP=%marker|%p|%c|%M|%m%n</Property>
   </Properties>

   <xi:include href="http://localhost:7001/log4j2config/getlog4j2xmlconfig?appCode=log4jConfig&amp;section=full" />
</Configuration>
```

Dinamically I load the following XML fragment from the servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="app.log" filePattern="app-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${Pattern}" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="OFF">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>
    <Logger name="mylog" level="warn" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Also, I placed a [new feature request to create a plugin for allowing a remote configuration](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-913) to be loaded.

I hope this can help some others in this situation.

Comment: I have a similar issue. However, I have 3 separate XMLs  - log4j2.xml which includes log4j2-appenders and log4j2-loggers. Whenever I change log level in loggers XML, it is not reflected until I "touch" log4j2.xml. Any help here?